# Как узнать сколько внутри массива значений python

Tags: python, sql, bs4, pymysql

У меня есть переменная которая хранит в себе 10 массивов.Как мне узнать сколько элементов содержаться в каждом массиве? 
**UPD**
После использование цикла

```
 for i in links:
        print(len(i))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD1**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD2**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymysql

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    links=soup.findAll(link_container_array[0],{link_container_array[1]:link_container_array[2]})
    for i in links:
    print(len(i))



def main(resource_allnews_link):
    url = resource_allnews_link
    (get_data(get_html(url)))


# < Подключение к базе данных.
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='news_portal',
                             charset='utf8',
                             autocommit=True)
cursor = connection.cursor()

# < Запрос для получения правил выдергивания контента.
cursor.execute('SELECT `resource_name`, `resource_url`, `resource_allnews_link`, `link_rule`, `mainblock`, `mainblock1`, `page_link`, `title`, `datetime`, `datetime1`, `text`, `text1` FROM `resources` WHERE 1')
resources=cursor.fetchall()

for resource in resources:
    resource_allnews_link=resource[2]
    content_rule=resource[3]
    link_container_array=content_rule.split(',')
    main(resource_allnews_link)

connection.close()

введите сюда код
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_with_len = [len(lst) for lst in lst_lsts]
```

в list_with_len список размеров списков lst_lsts

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in var:
    print(len(i))
```

Comment: Я использовал ваш пример.Но он вывел  много цифр.

Comment: Так и есть, он выводит десять чисел, каждое из них - длина массива

Comment: Можно ли сделать этот вывод как-то более читабельным?

Comment: Видимо в links у вас больше 10 массивов(или строк). Код выводит их длину

Comment: Не могли бы Вы скинуть код целиком?

Comment: У меня `links` содержит 10 массивов.Сверху прикрепил скриншот.

Comment: Код целиком? Хорошо.

Comment: Так. Он вывел 10 чисел, десять длин массивов, что еще надо?

Comment: Видите ли,при выводе.`print(len(links))` он мне показал длину не корректно.Т.к  при простом`print(links)` я считал.И  он показывает длину 1.На самом деле там длина больше.